# Filter "showpalette" of FFmpeg always returns the default palette

Tags: video, ffmpeg, gif, color-palette

I want to extract palette of GIF files with FFmpeg, and learned from the document that [filter "showpalette"](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#showpalette) can do that. But FFmpeg always returns the same default palette instead of the custom palette.

[image: default palette]

FFmpeg returns the same palette even for the two examples in [pkh.me's Post](http://blog.pkh.me/p/21-high-quality-gif-with-ffmpeg.html). Here's my code:

```
ffmpeg -i bbb-trans.gif -vf "showpalette" -y a%03d.png
ffmpeg -i bbb-nodither.gif -vf "showpalette" -y b%03d.png
```

Did I use the wrong command? Or it's a just bug of FFmpeg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the docs for [showpalette](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#showpalette) says, "*This filter is only relevant for pal8 pixel format frames*". Your test GIFs are full RGB.

You can still run

```
ffmpeg -i in.gif -vf palettegen=stats_mode=single,scale=30*iw:-1:flags=neighbor a%d.png
```

You can still use showpalette for pal8 GIFs

Comment: Thanks! I tried with your command, and it returns specific colors used or custom palette. And also tried to convert GIF into pal8 `ffmpeg -i bbb-nodither.gif -pix_fmt pal8 -y pal8.gif`, still the same default palette for both input GIFs. Do you know why?

Comment: If the input GIF is RGB, then there is no palette embedded in the GIF, so there's no custom palette to show. Hence it shows the default palette. If you convert to pal8 without running a palette generator, again it will use the default palette, so that is what will be shown.

Comment: About the two GIF files I mentioned, apply ''xxd" on them and I can see the palette inside, also got the result with ImageMagick "convert bbb-nodither.gif -format %c -depth 8 histogram:info:- |"

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what xxd does. With IM, looks like you're reducing the depth to 8 bit i.e. 256 colors and then displaying the 256 most used colors. That's the same thing as what my command ends up doing, to make the png.

Comment: `xxd` is just a tool to dump binary files in hex. IM is used to confirm that what I saw via xxd is a real palette - btw, it's strange that IM only return 254 colors, not 256.

Comment: Ok, so if I open the GIF in a hex editor, I should see the same thing? Where do I look i.e. how do you identify the palette section?

Comment: Refer [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GIF#Example_GIF_file) or [the spec](https://www.w3.org/Graphics/GIF/spec-gif89a.txt), you may find the palette from 0x00D to 0x30A, 3 bytes per color, 256 colors in total.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my summary --

Use the following command to get the default palette in ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -v fatal -i input.mp4 -vf "showpalette=30" -y palette-default.png
```

This command can generate specific palette based on the input file:

```
ffmpeg -v fatal -i input.mp4 -vf "palettegen,scale=30*iw:-1:flags=neighbor" -y palette-specific.png
```